# How to determine the lock screen is on the top of the other activity, or the other activity is on the top of the lock screen?

Tags: android, lockscreen, android-windowmanager, activity-manager

I encountered a problem,

- MyActivity is under the LockScreen, in this case, I need to launch MyActivity from framework by clicking volume button;
- MyActivity is on the top of Lockscreen, in this case, I do nothing.

But I don't know how to distinguish this two situations in framework. I know how to get the top activity, however, LockScreen isn't a activity.

I have a temporary solution, if MyActivity has `LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` property, set a custom system property, so I know whether launch MyActivity by this custom system property, but I don't think this is good.

I want to know whether there is a better solution.

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: sorry, this is my first question, I did not describe the problem clearly and I did not understand the rules, my fault.

Answer (score 0):

Register BroadcastReceiver  "android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" in CameraActivity
and detect whenever screen unlock event happens. Than Based on your requirement you can manage your code.

[USER_PRESENT Receiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT)

in your MainActivity inside oncreate you can check whether screen is locked or not

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) 
context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
if( keyguardManager .inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
 //it is locked
} else {
 //it is not locked
}
```

Comment: I know this method, but the more important thing is that I need to distinguish this case in third app, in this two situations, `inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()` will all return true. Thanks anyway.